# validate useragent versions

Tags: browser, version, user-agent

suppose this i a "beginner's" question and the answer might be to really understand regex, BUT I don't :-) right now i have a problem with different versions of firefox (in version 6 and previous, file.filename is the filereader method to get the name of a file, from version 7 on it is file.name).

so i actually test the follwing:

`1. ((/firefox/i).test(navigator.userAgent)&&!(/rv:7/i).test(navigator.userAgent)&&!(/rv:8/i).test(navigator.userAgent)) ? 'Moz' :`

`2. ((/firefox/i).test(navigator.userAgent)&&(/rv:7/i).test(navigator.userAgent))? 'Moz7' :`

`3. ((/firefox/i).test(navigator.userAgent)&&(/rv:8/i).test(navigator.userAgent))? 'Moz8' :`

which is not very effektive :-) i'd rather ask for "versions up to 6" and "versions from 7 up". how could i change my way?

thanks for hints

Comment: You really need to take a look at the SO FAQs - you havent accepted a single answer to any of your questions .... Accepted Answers = Reputation ....

Comment: thanks a lot for that! I never recognizes the sign to click on for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at quirksmode - there is a long section on browser detection  .... why re-invent the wheel ...

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

You can then use the output of that to perform `if (browser > versionx)` type code ...